# How to check if some affinity values exists in Ignite Cache?

Tags: java, caching, ignite, affinity

Is there any function like `cache.containsAffinity(T myField)` to check if such affinity value exists in the cache?

For example, I set cache config like this: `<AffinityKey<String>, Object>`, and write data using streamer:

`streamer.addData(new AffinityKey<>(idKey1, "a"), obj)`

`streamer.addData(new AffinityKey<>(idKey2, "b"), obj)`

`streamer.addData(new AffinityKey<>(idKey3, "c"), obj)`

How can I check if affinity value "a" exists in the cache and has related data entries, while affinity "f" has no related data?

Answer (score 0):

You can just to do `cache.get(new AffinityKey<>(idKey1, "a"))` and check returned value